# write into files created by ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have directory structure as follow:

```
../../../../../TESTS/Test_A/myTest_A/
../../../../../TESTS/Test_B/myTest_B/
../../../../../TESTS/Test_C/myTest_C/
../../../../../TESTS/Test_D/myTest_D/
```

Into each of them I create a file "myfile.txt" using the following ruby code:

```
Dir['../../../../../TESTS/Test_*/*/'].each do |dir|
  File.new File.join(dir, 'myfile.txt'), 'w+'
end
```

so far it works. Now I would like also to write something into the files accordingly after creation, the code looks now:

```
Dir['../../../../../TESTS/Test_*/*/'].each do |dir|
  File.new File.join(dir, 'myfile.txt'), 'w+'
  File.open('../../../../../TESTS/Test_*/*/myfile.txt','w+') do |f| 
    f.puts "HELLO"
  end
end
```

The files are empty? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File#open` doesn't handle `*` like `Dir#[]` does. You need to pass the exact file path.

```
Dir['../../../../../TESTS/Test_*/*/'].each do |path|
  File.open(path, 'w+') { |f| f.puts "HELLO" }
end
```

Comment: Exactly.  Note that `File.new` is extraneous, too.  Just substitute `File.join(dir, 'myfile.txt')` into "path" in the above code.